# Disable caching of attached css/js libraries for custom module?

Tags: 8, caching

I have been trying to disable caching during development so I followed drupals guide step by step: https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914

After doing this I would assume that the caching is completely disabled but when I am loading a js/css file for a specific module in mymodule/mymodule.libraries.yml I still have to clear all caches for me to see any updates.

**How do you disable caching for attached libraries in custom modules?**

**test_module.routing.yml**

```
test_module.test:
  path: '/test-me'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Testing module css cache'
    _controller: 'Drupal\test_module\Controller\TestController::test'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'TRUE'
```

**test_module.libraries.yml**

```
test:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    theme:
      test.css: {}
```

**TestController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\test_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

class TestController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function test()
    {
        return [
            "#markup" => Markup::create("<div class='test-class'>Hello World</div>"),
            '#attached' => [
                'library' => ['test_module/test']
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

**test.css**

```
.test-class {
    padding: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

If I change the background-color to red for example, and refresh the page (F5, Ctrl+F5, Ctrl+Shift+R, Right click refresh -> Clear cache and Hard Rest), it will not change to red until I clear all caches.

What piece am I missing to make this work? Or is it just not possible?

Note: It doesn't matter if I clear my browser cache at all (I currently have it disabled with devtools open)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the wrong track. Caching of static assets (and CSS files are static assets when you disable CSS/JS aggregation) has nothing to do with Drupal's cache. Disable the caching of `*.js` and `*.css` files on your web server instead (e.g in `.htaccess` if you are using Apache).

Comment: Yes, although Drupal tries to overcome this restriction by adding a cache buster query string, which is changed on a cache clear, so it appears that Drupal clears CSS, but in reality it doesn't.

Comment: The cache buster string only really works well with aggregation enabled and `drush cr`. With aggregation disabled, the query string for custom libraries is just the version number from the `library.info`, which is not really useful when iterating quickly over CSS on local dev

Comment: Without aggregation this works for CSS as well, only for JS you need to adjust the version number. What I meant, the OP expects that Drupal can clear CSS automatically, because Drupal can do it manually by `drush cr`. But Drupal doesn't have control over static CSS files, as you pointed out in the answer. Drupal simply invalidates the cache-buster each time the cache is cleared, without knowing whether CSS files were modified.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into disabling the caching in nginx and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Man I was so convinced drupal was caching it.  Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.  Updating nginx to not cache static files (css/js) saved the day.

Comment: You don't need to disable caching in nginx, you just need to remove the `version: VERSION` line in your libraries.yml file. Then it should just all work.

Answer (score 3):

You should simply remove the `version: VERSION` line, because this declares your library to be the same version as your Drupal core version, which does not change as often. By deleting this line, Drupal will add a default query string that changes after every cache rebuild/deployment, so it will naturally cache-bust.

See https://chromatichq.com/insights/drupal-libraries-version/ for more information on the VERSION value in libraries and why it shouldn't be used by anyone outside of core.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [js_cache_buster](https://www.drupal.org/project/js_cache_buster) module and add the `enable_buster: true` value to the js you want in your library.yml file. This will increment the `?v=` value each time the cache is cleared.