# Does disabling the Drupal cache also disable the CSS Cache?

Tags: theming, caching, 10

I am having trouble disabling caching in Drupal 10. To be more specific, I am trying to disable the cache using the Admin interface so that I don't have to manually edit any files in case I accidentally push my dev settings to the production environment in the future.

## Attempt 1

I found [this Drupal 10 article](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/development-tools/disable-caching) and followed the "Disabling Twig Caching the easy way" section. Following the instructions, I opened **Admin -> Configuration -> Development -> Development Settings** & toggled the following options to "on":

- Twig Development Mode
- Twig Debug mode
- Disable Twig Cache
- Do not cache markup

This seemed to enable the Twig development comments, but I still have to manually flush the cache whenever I make a change to CSS. My end goal is to add something like gulp and enable live reloading whenever a change is made so I need the CSS to refresh without having to flush the cache.

## Attempt 2

I also tried going to **Admin -> Configuration -> Development -> Performance** and set the Caching to `<no caching>`.

This also didn't seem to resolve the issue. Whenever I make a change in the CSS, I have to go to the admin toolbar dropdown and *Flush All Caches* to see the changes.

## Attempt 3 (Trying the duplicate question solution)

My question was closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/272377/disable-caching-of-attached-css-js-libraries-for-custom-module). The answer said this was likely an Apache setting and to disable caching on `.htaccess` but did not explain how to do this.

I found a [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891965/how-to-disable-cache-of-apache) that explained how to disable caching in Apache, and more importantly, how to add `.htaccess` to project root and what to put in to disable caching. I attempted the solution, but it did not work.

I took the below steps:

1. Found `.htaccess` file in my `/web/` directory which is my project root
2. There was already a large configuration there, so I added in my snippet. I cut out all the existing code, but my snippet looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header unset ETag
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
      Header set Pragma "no-cache"
      Header set Expires "Wed, 12 Jan 1980 05:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

3. Ensured `httpd.conf` is loading mod_rewrite
4. Added `EnableSendfile` off to `httpd.conf`
5. Restarted Apache

Following this, I tried refreshing the page to see CSS changes but they were still not taking effect until I Flushed the Cache.

## Additional Info

- This is in a local development environment on my computer not an external host
- I am not using the color module which is known to cause similar issues

Comment: Have you changed the deployment identifier in settings.php or the module version string in its info file?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I tried the following: (1) In my info file, I removed the `version: VERSION` line as per the duplicate answer. (2) In my `settings.php` file, the line `# $settings['deployment_identifier'] = \Drupal::VERSION;` was commented. I attempted to refresh with the line commented and uncommented, but in both cases I still had to manually flush the cache.

Comment: Just to add to my above comment, I also tried one more attempt where I removed the VERSION line from my `libraries.yml` file.

Comment: Close, but not exactly: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3371822 and I think I said the module info file not the libraries file.

Comment: Yes you're right, but after trying, i read through the posted duplicate answer a few more times and saw it mentioned libraries as well, which is why I tried that in my second attempt. I read through the link you posted, but I'm not too sure what it is suggesting to do. It says "Always add deployment_identifer to aggregate hashes." but I do not know what this means, or what to set the deployment identifier to. I am still learning Drupal and this concept is difficult for me.

Comment: Try setting it to just some random string.

Comment: Okay, I tried setting a random string in `info.yml` but still same issue.

Comment: I meant: in the deployment identifier.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that. I added `$settings['deployment_identifier'] = 'A1234';` but I still have to flush the cache every time I change CSS. Just to confirm, should VERSION be removed from the info file or left in? This was automatically put in when I used starterkit to generate the theme.

Comment: As I understand it, the version in either the libraries or info file must *change*, not be removed, and to be sure, this should be Drupal 10.1.